# How to extract an array of all HTML tags from a textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to extract all the HTML tags like from this `<body id = "myid"> .... </body>` i just want to extract `<body id ="myid">` similarly i want to extract all the HTML tags with attributes and using javascript.

I've tried using regex to make an array of all the tags inclosed between '< & >'

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    // Get value on button click and show alert
    $("#btn_parse").click(function(){
        var str = $("#data").val();
        var arr =  str.split(/[<>]/);
        $('#result').text(arr);
    });
});
</script>
```

but it's creating an array arr containing empty and garbage also it's removing angular brackets '<>'
which I don't want.
SO in nutshell I want a script that takes

```
str ='mystring ... <htmltag id='myid' class='myclass'>i_don't_want_anythin_from_here</htmltag> ...';
```

and produces an array like:

```
arr = ["<htmltag id='myid' class='myclass'>","</htmltag>",...];
```

Comment: What is your real usage? Using a regexp would be quite painful, why not using querySelector or jQuery to get every node that match your query, then do whatever you want with that result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one dirty way. Add it to the dom so it can be accessed via normal DOM functions, then remove the text, and split the tags and push to an array.

```js
str ="mystring ... <htmltag id='myid' class='myclass'>i_don't_want_anythin_from_here</htmltag> ...";

div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = str;
document.body.appendChild(div);

tags = div.querySelectorAll("*");
stripped = [];
tags.forEach(function(tag){
  tag.innerHTML = "";
  _tag = tag.outerHTML.replace("></",">~</");
  stripped.push(_tag.split("~"));
});

console.log(stripped);

document.body.removeChild(div);
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I wanted. 

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can also get the input from a "live" page then the following should do what you want:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll("*")]
  .map(el=>el.outerHTML.match(/[^>]+>/)[0]+"</"+el.tagName.toLowerCase()+">")
```

The above will combine the beginning and end tags into one string like

```
<div class="js-ac-results overflow-y-auto hmx3 d-none"></div>
```

And here is the same code applied on an arbitrary string:

```js
var mystring="<div class='all'><htmltag id='myid' class='myclass'>i_don't_want_anythin_from_here</htmltag><p>another paragraph</p></div>";

const div=document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML=mystring;

let res=[...div.querySelectorAll("*")].map(el=>el.outerHTML.match(/[^>]+>/)[0]+"</"+el.tagName.toLowerCase()+">")

console.log(res)
```